# Changing icon of geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, esri-geodatabase, catalog-window

Is there a way to change the icon of a geodatabase?

I have a geodatabase from ArcMap 10.2 (have now upgraded to 10.7) and want to distinguish between the old and the newer geodatabases.

Comment: Having recently passed Halloween, this made me think of symbolization of older file geodatabase "folders" with increasing numbers of cobwebs until a gravestone is masked behind it... In reality, I expect this would have to be an enhancement request through ideas.esri.com